# The choice of using DAL and web2py to connect PostgreSQL database to a web server

Tags: python, web-services, postgresql, web2py

I have a database in postgresql and I have to connect it to a web server. I'm familiar with python programming but not web programing. I have some information about DAL (Database Abstraction Layer) to write my queries from within python. I have to generalize my queries to functions. Is it a good idea to to do it using DAL and subsequently use web2py technology to connect it to a web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web2py DAL is a great choice if being database agnostic is a requirement for you. This means the DAL dynamically generates the SQL in real time using the specified dialect for the database back end, so that you do not have to write SQL code or learn different SQL dialects; therefore, your application will be portable among different types of databases. Since SQL is generated dynamically by the DAL, it ensures that all inserted data is properly escaped, which prevents Injection Flaws and makes SQL Injection impossible.

Additionally, although I had not found anything mentioned in the web2py book about how to automatically generate a model from an existing database, there is a way to quickly and easily create a database model from an existing PostgreSQL database by using script available on github created by Mariano Reingart, who based it on a script to "generate schemas from dbs" (mysql) created by Alexandre Andrade. The script is used to create a web2py db model from a PostgreSQL database.

Since I was using a MSSQL database, I needed a similar script, but I couldn't find anything, so I made minor edits to the script, specifically around the SQL and datatypes so that it was more in line with MSSQL, and it worked like a charm. I had a database model of about 150 tables created in seconds and it saved me a lot of time.

```
https://github.com/phektus/cvstash/blob/master/scripts/extract_pgsql_models.py
```

I hope this helps others out there who are looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

web2py DAL has support for Postgres and you can use it within web2py or you can take only the dal.py and use with your favorite project/framework.

For existing databases I recommend you to read the chapter 6 of http://web2py.com/book

I have multiple apps running with Postgres and it works very nice!